# How to find a pattern in text with Regular Expression (Extended), grep and Bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to match any of the following pattern possibilities inside a text:

```
(X)
( X )
(  X  )
(x)
( x )
(  x  )
```

Where "X" can be any single alphanumeric character (including "*.+"), surrounded by any quantity of spaces or none at all.

This is what I got so far:

```
export A=$(cat <<'EOL'
subject     Re: [ATPC] Teste de eMailForm
> - - - - - - - -
> 1 ) QUEM SOU EU?
> (  ) Sou cervejeiro profissional
> ( X ) Sou um bebum nato, não ligo pra marca
> (  ) Sou exigente, bebo apenas artesanais
> - - - - - - - -
EOL
)

echo "$A" | grep -E "\( * \)"
#echo "$A" | grep -E "\(*^[[:space:]]*\)"
```

And it returns:

```
> (  ) Sou cervejeiro profissional
> (  ) Sou exigente, bebo apenas artesanais
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Edit: I expect to get this line from my example:

`> ( X ) Sou um bebum nato, não ligo pra marca`

Comment: `\(\s*\w\s*\)`? In your regex, `"\( * \)"` first space is repeated zero or more times but following by another space. It doesn't match single character(`x` shown in examples.).

Comment: Try `grep -E "\( *[a-zA-Z0-9*.+]+ *\)"`. If you need the value to be equal to the whole line, you will need anchors, `"^\( *[a-zA-Z0-9*.+]+ *\)$"`

Comment: Can you give a proper i/p file with an expected output?

Comment: Question edited, thanks.

Comment: `"\( *[a-zA-Z0-9*.+]+ *\)"` and `"\(\s*\w\s*\)"` did the magic, thanks @Wiktor Stribizew and @Tushar.

Comment: @Roger: I added an answer with explanations. Note that `\w` matches `_`, too. Not sure you want to allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match 1 or more alphanuemric or `*`, `.`, `+` symbols inside `(...)`, you may use

```
grep -E "\( *[a-zA-Z0-9*.+]+ *\)"
```

If there should only be a single char other than spaces inside the parentheses, remove the `+` after `]`:

```
grep -E "\( *[a-zA-Z0-9*.+] *\)"
```

**Details**:

- `\(` - matches a literal `(` (since `-E` enabled the Extended Regular Expression mode and the `(` should be escaped in it to match a literal `)`)
- `*` - 0+ spaces (can be replaced with `[[:space:]]*` to match any whitespace)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9*.+]` - 1 char that is either an ASCII letter, digit, `*`, `.` or `+` (if 1 or more occurrences are expected, add `+` after `]`)
- `*` - see above
- `\)` - a literal  `)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` with the power of Perl regular expressions:

```
echo "$A" | grep -P '\(\s*\S+\s*\)'
```

Comment: Using the experimental `-P` option makes matching slower. There is no need to use the PCRE (it is not actually a *Perl* regex) regex here, as the pattern is rather basic and Extended Regular Expression mode can cope with this just as easily.

Comment: I agree @WiktorStribiżew and I’m aware of that mater. I would chose `Perl` itself for processing large amounts of data.  I don’t believe performance is an issue for this particular example and the Perl regex seems clearer for me.